# Fitting two images inside two Bootstrap columns

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to create my first Bootstrap website and I came across my first problems. My website structure includes one row in the header which is separated into to columns: one for the logo and one is for ad space.

Below this row, there is another one with just one column which is just some kind of container colored in grey.

On my large screen, the ad space looks nice, but when starting to resize my browser, it's becoming quite weird... The ad space is going below the logo and **under** the row below.

I'm unable to provide a JSFiddle link since I don't know how to import the Bootstrap CSS there, so I'll show you the code here and some of my simple webpage's images.

**HTML:** http://pastebin.com/N62Ps5MT

**LESS:** http://pastebin.com/0F3nzZ33

*Large display:*
[image: Desktop sized webpage]

---

*Large. Just a little bit smaller:*
[image: Just a little smaller]

---

*Medium display:*
[image: Even smaller]

---

*Small display:*

[image: Very Small view]

---

I would really appreciate some help. I'm really interested on learning how to solve Bootstrap problems via different methods.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot confirm this behaviour, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxmaK/1/show). At least with Firefox 20, the ads go below the logo and stay there, even with a very small display. This has nothing to do with bootstrap, maybe it's one of the other CSS of JS includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you nest your rows in col-lg-12, there seems no reason to do that. I don't expect this will cause your problems
2. the xs-classes never stack, your ads are not responsive (maybe try to add .img-resposnive). The width of your ads images can be bigger then the total width of the col-xs-7
3. You should apply the Responsive column resets, see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets